# JavaScript Member Array Becomes Undefined when Referenced by Class Method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a minesweeper game in JavaScript, and I'm making it so that every time the user clicks a square on the screen, it calls `reveal_tile()` on a `Minesweeper` object. `Minesweeper` comes with two members: `board`, which stores the entire board, and `player_board`, which stores all of the tiles that are currently visible to the player (those that are not visible are marked with -2). To implement `reveal_tile()`, I need to reference both `board` and `player_board`, but when I try using `this.board` or `this.player_board`, it returns undefined. Is there something I'm missing?

Here's my code for `reveal_tile()`:

```
    reveal_tile(i,j){ //updates the player board to reveal the contents of Board[i][j]
        const zero_tiles = [];

        this.player_board[i][j]=this.board[i][j];
        if (this.board[i][j] == 0){
            zero_tiles.push([i,j]);
        }
        
        while(zero_tiles.length!=0){
            for (let di = -1; di <2; di++){
                for (let dj = -1; dj <2; dj++){
                    if (this.player_board[i+di][j+dj]==-2){ //if a tile next to a zero tile hasn't been revealed
                        this.player_board[i+di][j+dj]=this.board[i+di][j+dj];
                        if (this.board[i+di][j+dj]==0){
                            zero_tiles.push([i+di,j+dj]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the context it's called in:

```
this.reveal_tile(reserved_tile[0],reserved_tile[1]);
```

As well as the entire constructor (if that's important):

```
    constructor(first_click_row,first_click_column) {
        const reserved_tile = [first_click_row,first_click_column];
        const rows = 8;
        const columns = 10;
        const N_mines = 10;
        const directions = [-1, 0, 1];
        const board = [];
        const row = [];
        const available_tiles = [];
        let n_available_tiles = rows*columns;
        let tile //might use this idk

        for(let i = 0; i<columns;i++){
            row.push(0);
        }
        for(let i = 0; i<rows;i++){
            board.push(Array.from(row));
        }
        for (let i = 0; i <rows; i++){
            for (let j = 0; j <columns; j++){
                available_tiles.push([i,j]);
            }
        }


        for (let di = -1; di <2; di++){ //remove tiles surrounding the player's first click so every game is playable
            for (let dj = -1; dj <2; dj++){

                tile = [reserved_tile[0]+di,reserved_tile[1]+dj]

                available_tiles.splice(
                    available_tiles.findIndex((element) => element[0] == tile[0] && element[1] == tile[1]),
                    1
                ); 

            }
        }

        let I, J;
        let mine_tile
        

        let x;
        for (let i = 0; i < N_mines; i++){ //place mines
            x = this.randint(0,available_tiles.length-1)
            mine_tile = available_tiles.splice(x,1);
            mine_tile = mine_tile[0];
            board[mine_tile[0]][mine_tile[1]] = -1;
            I = mine_tile[0];
            J = mine_tile[1];
            for (let di = -1; di <2; di++){ //increment the bomb count of all surrounding tiles 
                for (let dj = -1; dj <2; dj++){
                    if ((di != 0 || dj != 0) && (di + I >= 0) && (dj + J >= 0) && (di+I <rows) && (dj+J <columns) && (board[I+di][J+dj]!=-1)){
                        board[I+di][J+dj] = board[I+di][J+dj] + 1;
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
        
        
        const player_row = [];
        const player_board = [];
        
        for(let i = 0; i<columns;i++){
            player_row.push(-2);
        }
        for(let i = 0; i<rows;i++){
            player_board.push(Array.from(row));
        }
        console.log(board)
        this.reveal_tile(reserved_tile[0],reserved_tile[1]);

    } //end constructor
```

(The reason my constructor is so long is because I was initially going to implement the board creation in a method `create_board()`, but I ran into a similar issue where I could not reference class members, so it's implemented in the constructor for now).

Comment: This looks like an infinite loop: `while(zero_tiles.length!=0)`. You never remove anything from `zero_tiles` in the loop, so it will always be more than 0.

Comment: The constructor never creates `this.board` or `this.player_board.` It has local variables `board` and `player_board`, but never adds them as properties.

Comment: @Barmar That fixed it, thank you! Also, thanks for pointing out the infinite loop